# Public interface, internal functionality

Tags: design-patterns, interface

I have an interface which is currently public.  This is passed to the client as a representation of a type (same application but I cannot modify calling code beyond changes types).

A -> B.GetIntrerface();

A -> B.SendInterface(A.InterfaceIGot);

Is essentially what I'm saying here.

With that in mind, if I want to have internal functionality (so that the caller cannot see it), and I do not want to pass a concrete class to the caller, is there a design pattern that supports this?

Can I do:

```
A.otherInterface = A.instanceOfB.GetInterface();
instanceOfB.SendInterface(A.otherInterface);
```

Where otherInterface is public.

And internally in `SendInterface` ?

```
interfacePassedIn.DoSomethingInternal();
```

I know I could downcast, but it seems messy.  Is there an established design pattern for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Pass an abstract class to the caller.

Comment: They would still be aware of more functionality than they should be.  I want to limit what is exposed and avoid downcasting if possible?  Or am I dreaming of a pattern that can't exist here?